# Get error when running a laravel app in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I was used **nginx** and **php-fpm** in ubuntu, and I had edited the files like following:
**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        root /usr/test/public/;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9999;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #fixes timeouts
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

**/etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9999
```

And I also changed the permissions like following:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/test/public
chmod 755 /usr/test
chmod -R 755 /usr/test/bootstrap/cache
chmod -R 755 /usr/test/AppName/storage
```

But when I tried to run a simple laravel project, it shows me this error message:

```
The stream or file "/usr/test/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Why is that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others you can refer here permission things

Comment: Just `chmod -R 755 /usr/test/storage`

Comment: @SanK ok, let me take a look

Comment: @kerbholz I tried, but still got the same error.

Comment: Hmmm, did you also `chown -R www-data:www-data` that folder?

Comment: @kerbholz How, it works! I tried chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/test , thanks man!

Answer (score -1):

try `chmod -R 777` also 
did u generate app key for your application? if not please follow below steps
on your terminal type:              `php artisan key:generate` 
then add it to your .env file 
APP_KEY=YOUR_GENERATED_KEY

it may be hidden, do ctrl + h in your project folder to view it.